# Examples for carrying out various op's on text files in FreeBSD kernel module

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, kernel-module, vfs

Could anyone give some simple examples for creating,reading,writing operations on regular files in a FreeBSD kernel?  I am new to FreeBSD's VFS world and was trying to explore things via examples.

I already came across the below link which gave an overview of how to read from an already existing file:

[Examples for reading text files in FreeBSD kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512716/examples-for-reading-text-files-in-freebsd-kernel-module)

I was looking for similar examples where i get to know how to create a file and how to write to the file.

Really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

ktrace (kern/kern_ktrace.c), accounting (kern/kern_acct.c), coredumping (kern/kern_sig.c).... or you can check how writing from userspace is implemented and steal that.

Comment: I don't think checking the user-space to kernel space application programs would help me here.

Comment: I don't know how to parse your comment. First 3 mechanisms I mentioned open/create a file and write to it on their own operating only in kernel space, so there you have working implementations that can be used as an example. There was an additional remark that e.g. following 'open' syscall implementation would have told you what to call within the kernel in order to open a file, and doing so for 'write', well, would tell you how to write.