# Writing a FreeBSD kernel module that handles arbitrary interrupt and output to device

Tags: c, unix, kernel, freebsd, bsd

I would like to write a FreeBSD kernel module that could accept some arbitrary interrupts and upon receiving these interrupt, output some data to an arbitrary device. Currently, I'm facing several issues:

1. How would I acquire interrupts through a specific IRQ? On Linux there is the `request_irq()` call but it seems there's no similar API for FreeBSD... Say, I want to be able to detect all the keyboard interrupt through my kernel module (the keyboard is on irq1), how would I do that? (On Linux it is possible through calling `free_irq(1, NULL)` and `request_irq(1, ...)`, correct me if I'm wrong though).
2. Is it possible at all to write to a device file under /dev through a kernel module? I've read the question [Example for reading text files in FreeBSD kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512716/examples-for-reading-text-files-in-freebsd-kernel-module); following this example I was able to do read/write on regular files, but not a device file under /dev (the "device" was a pseudo ["echo device"](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/arch-handbook/driverbasics-char.html), the classical one used in char device examples). I was able to open the file though.
   I do understand that it is considered as a bad practice to do file I/O's in kernel, but I could not think any other way... If anyone has a better solution please tell me. (i.e. write to a device through its `device_t` node?)

The reason I was doing this in a kernel is that I really need all interrupts to be hit, and running it in the user space has the risk of missing interrupts due to kernel threads preempting user threads (the interrupts could come very frequent).

I would also appreciate if anyone could provide me with some other ideas on how to implement this program (basically, the idea is a kernel module that could do the job of a microcontroller...)

Comment: You are very brave and courageous.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an IRQ handler with [`bus_setup_intr`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bus_setup_intr&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports).

Normally, what one would do in this situation is to have a driver collect the interrupts and any other useful data, and export it through a device, and then a (real-time maybe?) process in user-space can read from one device, do whatever it needs to do, and write to the other device.